# Why doesn't my javascript function execute? Error: Cannot read property 'change' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

It seems that if I just rename `public events: Eventing = new Eventing();` in my User class to anything other than `events` it would stop working. I understand that as long as the name of that property matches with the name of the property in eventing.ts, it works. Why ? That is what I want to find out.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-playground-kqqtss?file=user.ts)

**index.ts**

```
import { User } from "./user";
const user = new User();
const on = user.on;

user.on("change", () => {
  alert("yo");
});
user.trigger("change");
```

**user.ts**

```
import { Eventing } from "./eventing";

export interface UserProps {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}
export class User {
  public events: Eventing = new Eventing(); //stops working if renamed to anything other than events
  constructor() {}
  get on() {
    return this.events.on;
  }
  get trigger() {
    return this.events.trigger;
  }
}
```

**eventing.ts**

```
type Callback = () => void;

export class Eventing {
  events: { [key: string]: Callback[] } = {};  

  on(eventName: string, callback: Callback): void {
    const handlers = this.events[eventName] || [];  
    handlers.push(callback);  
    this.events[eventName] = handlers;  
  }

  trigger(eventName: string): void {
    const handlers = this.events[eventName];
    if (!handlers || handlers.length === 0) {
      return;
    }
    handlers.forEach(callback => {
      callback();
    });
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

`this` inside User class refers to User class itself. But since User class has a property called event that is an instance of Eventing class, when I try to execuet `this.event.on()`  it must execute, right? Why won't it execute? Why does the property name has to match with the one in Eventing class?

Comment: I didnt downvote, but what exactly is the error ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai Cannot read property 'change' of undefined

Comment: text of question says `rename I public events: Eventing = new Eventing(); in my User class to anything other than events it would stop working` ... comment in code says `stops working if renamed to events` ... that's a contradiction isn't it?

Comment: @Bravo that was type. Fixed the comment.

Comment: Aku acknowledges your typo :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because you are binding `user` `this` to `on` and `trigger` methods here:

```
get on() {
    return this.events.on;
}

get trigger() {
  return this.events.trigger;
}
```

So inside `on` and `trigger` methods, `this` will be instance of `User` and not `Eventing`.

You could turn `on` and `trigger` in lamba function or just `bind` methods like this (e.g. you want to change property to `foos`):

```
public foos: Eventing = new Eventing();
get on() {
    return this.events.on.bind(this.foos);
}

get trigger() {
    return this.events.trigger.bind(this.foos);
}
```

Comment: So as I understand it, `this` inside `User` class refers to `User`  class itself. But there is a property inside User called event that points to eventing class. So it should work right? Why does it only work when the names are same in eventing and user class?

Comment: @SamuraiJack Actually other way around - this inside Eventing class is User instance (you can debug that - in on and trigger methods), because you are returning this.events.on/this.events.trigger which binds user to those methods.

Comment: Third option is to bind Eventing methods in Eventing constructor to that instance like - this.on = this.on.bind(this) and this.trigger = this.trigger.bind(this);

Comment: Its how javascript works :D Try reading about bind, this references and scoping in javascript.

Comment: Let me say out loud what I am thinking. So, since I am returning `this.events.trigger` from my `User` class. And then passing values to it from my index.ts, the `trigger()` that belongs to the `Eventing` has a `this` that points to `User` class? And since User class has no trigger method. It therefore doesn't work?

Comment: Exactly! That's why you have to somehow bind that method to Eventing instance - either in Eventing constructor, within User class (maybe bad approach) or you can define your Eventing methods as lamba function which should resolve this correctly.